# Why does my sed command print ps title?

Tags: sed

Why does my sed command print ps title here:

```
$ ps | sed -E "s/\s*([[:digit:]]+)\s+.*/\1/"
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
26636
26637
54326
```

Why `PID TTY      TIME CMD` line passes the filter? Ending regexp with `g`, `p`, didn't help.

---

```
$ ps | sed -n -E "s/\s*([[:digit:]]+)\s+.*/\1/"
$ ps | sed -E "s/\s*([[:digit:]]+)\s+.*/\1/"
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
17966
17967
54326
$ ps | sed -E "s/\s*([[:digit:]]+)\s+.*/\1/p"
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
18429
18429
18430
18430
54326
54326
$ ps | sed -n -E "s/\s*([[:digit:]]+)\s+.*/\1/p"
18734
18735
54326
$ ps | sed -n -E "s/\s*([[:digit:]]+)\s+.*/\1/g"
$
```

Looks random :)

---

And why does this print title:

```
$ ps | sed -n -E "s/^\s*([^\s]+)\s*([^\s]+)\s*([^\s]+)\s*([^\s]+).*$/\1/p"
PID TTY          TIME 
34666
34667
54326
```

Comment: It's random if you don't understand it. `-n` turns off the default printing of every line (after possibly having been modified by the `sed` code). The `p` at the end forces printing if the substitution was performed. Without `-n` but with `p`, you get doubles of everything that the substitution acted upon and a single copy of everything that the substitution did not act upon.

Comment: btw, if you're using the linux procps version of `ps` , you can suppress headers in the output with `ps h ...` or `ps --no-headers ...`

Answer (score 5):

Because `s/pattern/replacement` does nothing if `pattern` doesn't match, and `sed` prints the pattern space by default. If you want to print *only* the substitution result, add `-n` (to suppress default printing) and `p` (to print the pattern space after a successful substitution):

```
ps | sed -n -E "s/\s*([[:digit:]]+)\s+.*/\1/p"
```

---

You may wish to tell `ps` to output only the PID, so no post processing is required:

```
ps -opid=
```

(This will likely output one fewer result, since `ps` won't include the `sed` process.)

Comment: With just `n` is returns nothing, with `-E ... /p` it prints lines twice, and only with `-n -E ... /p` it works. Why? Is there any logic in such behavior?

Comment: @Dims yes that's exactly the logic: `-n` controls whether lines are printed generally, while the `p` modifier prints if the substitution succeeds (regardless of whether `-n` is in effect)